Solution verification for a proof that $x^3+py^3+p^2z^3=0$ has no nontrivial solution
I was asked to prove that given a prime $p\geq 3$, the equation $x^3+py^3+p^2z^2=0$ has exactly one solution in the integers.
Here is my proof:
Clearly $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$ is a solution. Let's assume that $x_0,y_0,z_0$ are not all zero, and  solve $x^3+py^3+p^2z^3=0$, where $|x_0|+|y_0|+|z_0|$ is minimal. We get
$x_0^3+py_0^3+p^2z_0^3\equiv 0\pmod p$, and because $py_0^3\equiv p^2z_0^3\equiv 0\pmod p$, we get $x_0^3\equiv 0\pmod p$, so that $x_0\equiv 0\pmod p$, which gives that there exists an $x_1$ with $x_0=px_1$. We thus get $p^3x_1^3+py_0^3+p^2z_0^3=0$ so that $p^2x_1^3+y_0^3+pz_0^3=0$. In a similar manner, we get that there is a $y_1$ with $y_0=py_1$
so that $$p^2x_1^3+p^3y_1^3+pz_0^3=0\implies px_1^3+p^2y^3_1+z_0^3=0.$$
In a similar manner, we get that there is a $z_1$ with $z_0=pz_1$
so that $$px_1^3+p^2y^3_1+p^3z_1^3=0\implies x_1^3+py^3_1+p^2z_1^3=0.$$ We get that the  additional solution $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$  to $x^3+py^3+p^2z^3=0$ satisfies $$|x_1|\leq |x_0|,|y_1|\leq |y_0|,|z_1|\leq |z_0|,$$ and because one of $x_0,y_0,z_0$ is nonzero, we get $|x_1|+|y_1|+|z_1|<|x_0|+|y_0|+|z_0|$ which is a contradiction to the choice of $x_0,y_0,z_0$ since clearly not all $x_1,y_1,z_1$ are zero. We get that the equation $x^3+py^3+p^2z^3=0$ has exactly one solution in the integers.
I didn't use the fact that $p$ is an odd prime, and worse, and didn't use the fact that $p$ is prime!
Is my solution correct, and if not, how can it be fixed?

You stated that $x^{3}\equiv 0\pmod{p}\Rightarrow x\equiv 0\pmod{p}$, which assumes that $p$ is squarefree.

COMMENT.- It seems your solution is correct. Anyway an easier answer is as follow:
If $x$ is distinct of $0$ and $p$ then we have $pt^3+p^2s^3=-1$ where both $t$ and $s$ are elements of $\mathbb F_p$ so we have $0\equiv-1\pmod p$ which is impossible.

This only shows that $p$ divides $x$ I think? Or am I missing something?
